# Проблема с адаптивным дизайном

Tags: html, css

Есть два блока `<main>` и `<aside>` html:

```
<aside></aside>
<main></main>
```

css на десктопах:

```
aside {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

На десктопах все так как на картинке, и меня это полностью устраивает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На мобильниках css выглядит так

```
aside {
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно что бы блок `<aside>` на мобилках располагался под `<main>`.

**В идеале решить эту проблему нужно без `flexbox`.**

Comment: А можно поинтересовать, чем flexbox не угодил? Вроде поддержка есть во всех современных браузерах

Comment: @andreymal, Разметка остального проекта совместима с ie8, и хотя поддержка как бы уже не приоритетна, ломать все одной маленькой фишечкой очень не хочется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например: поменять местами в `html` сайдбар и контент + `calc` для `main`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


main {
  background: #0084ff;
  height: 300px;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 300px);
}

aside {
  background: #00ffa8;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  aside,
  main{
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>main</main>
<aside>aside</aside>
```

Вариант с `display:table`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


main {
  background: #0084ff;
  height: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
}

aside {
  background: #00ffa8;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  
  display: table-cell;
}

.wrap {
  display: table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  
  .wrap,
  aside,
  main{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <main>main</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</div>
```